# How to access an object member from event callback function in a class object on Ecmascript 6 (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

I've got this :

```
class Register {

    render(){
        return (<div onchange={this.aFunction}></div>)
    };

    aFunction(event){
        this.printSomething();  //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    }

    printSomething(){
        console.log('Horray');
    }

}
```

How can I call printSomething from within aFunction? Es6 really confuses me.

Thank you.

Comment: Try: `return (<div onchange={this.aFunction.bind(this)}></div>)`. Although I'm not familiar with this curly-brace syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll notice that when using ES6 classes with React [a lot has changed](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html).

Also, ES6 classes don't [autobind](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding) the way the ES5 `React.createClass` would.

As a result, you need to properly bind the `this` of the function

---

You have two options

#### 1. use an arrow function

```
render(){
    return <div onchange={event => this.aFunction(event)}></div>;
}
```

#### 2. use a binding

```
render(){
    return <div onchange={this.aFunction.bind(this)}></div>;
}
```

---

I assume you're using React.js for this. If you are, you need to update

```
class Register
```

to

```
class Register extends React.Component
```

Comment: I am, thank you for your answer, and don't worry my class is much more complex than this, I just simplified it and forgot to add the extension here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `this` on `render` is bound on the div.

```
var foo = new Register;
var div = foo.render();
div.onchange(); // this is div, not foo
foo.aFunction(); // doesn't throw TypeError.
```